# What is the best way to clean up data for a Power BI paginated report?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery

I recently discovered Power Query and don't have enough experience to transform the data to prepare for a paginated report I need to create in Power BI.  For each inspection, I have three rows of data. The parent serial number and two child serial numbers.  The customer wants to see only one row per serial number.  How can I display the values of the child serial number on the same row as the parent.  The tricky part is that there are two columns for the test results.  One column for numeric results and another column for text results, (Accept/Reject), depending on the type of inspection.  The product is a cord with fittings on each end. The child serial number is the parent serial number with a "-X" appended for one end and a "-Y" for the other end. If the parent serial number has an inspection, then there will be no results for the child serial numbers.  Likewise, if the child serial number has an inspection, then there will not be a result for the parent.  My thought is to add an "X" column and a "Y" column and display the child value on the same row as the parent serial.

| SERIAL | INSPECTION | NUMERIC | TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SN001 | INSP_A | 0.01 |  |
| SN001-X | INSP_A |  |  |
| SN001-Y | INSP_A |  |  |
| SN001 | INSP_B |  |  |
| SN001-X | INSP_B |  | ACCEPT |
| SN001-Y | INSP_B |  | ACCEPT |

Target

| SERIAL | INSPECTION | NUMERIC | TEXT | X DATA | Y DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SN001 | INSP_A | 0.01 |  |  |  |
| SN001 | INSP_B |  |  | ACCEPT | ACCEPT |

The X data and Y data columns should accept alphanumeric data.  This is step 1.  As you can see, I still have two rows for SN001.  The next step is to transpose the inspections across the top with the data below.

| SERIAL | INSP_A | INSP_B (X DATA) | INSP_B (Y DATA) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SN001 | 0.01 | ACCEPT | ACCEPT |

Is this possible?  There are up to 20 inspections, but luckily, the customer only wants to see eight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to the first step, try this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCvYzMDBU0lHy9AsOiHcEMgz0wHylWB2opG4EsjSqVCROKZiEE4aeCDQpR2dn14AQbIaiKYgFAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [SERIAL = _t, INSPECTION = _t, NUMERIC = _t, TEXT = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SERIAL", type text}, {"INSPECTION", type text}, {"NUMERIC", type number}, {"TEXT", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([NUMERIC] <> null or [TEXT] <> "")),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "SERIAL", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"-"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"SERIAL", "END"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Split Column by Delimiter",null,"TEXT",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"END"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Replaced Value", List.Distinct(#"Replaced Value"[END]), "END", "TEXT")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

The final version is OK for displaying data but not for storing data but you could get to it like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCvYzMDBU0lHy9AsOiHcEMgz0wHylWB2opG4EsjSqVCROKZiEE4aeCDQpR2dn14AQbIaiKYgFAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [SERIAL = _t, INSPECTION = _t, NUMERIC = _t, TEXT = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SERIAL", type text}, {"INSPECTION", type text}, {"NUMERIC", type number}, {"TEXT", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "SERIAL", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"SERIAL", "END"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Combined", each if [NUMERIC] = null then [TEXT] else Number.ToText([NUMERIC]), type text),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "PivotColumn", each [INSPECTION] & (if [END] = null then "" else " (" & [END] & " DATA)"), type text),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"SERIAL", "Combined", "PivotColumn"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each ([Combined] <> "")),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[PivotColumn]), "PivotColumn", "Combined")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

To see how these work, paste the code into the Advanced Editor and step through the Applied Steps in the query editor to see the transformed table at each step.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Let me start out by saying that the above code worked... somewhat.  When I applied it to my actual data, there is extra blank column for each inspection.  What I am looking for is if there is no data for X or Y, then only show one column for that inspection with either the numeric or text result.  If there is data for X and Y, then there two columns.  One for X and one for Y. (If possible, group them under one header for that inspection, and then just label the columns X or Y).  Other than that, it worked just fine.  One row for each serial number with all the needed data in that row.

Comment: Sorry. I can't easily write code for different data that I can't see with additional constraints that were not explained in your post. If you have other input and output in mind, then you'll need to provide examples of each.